# How to copy and paste arguments into function parenthesis?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I constantly need to copy existing variable names or expressions as arguments for my current typing function:

```
// int TyrionLannister;

int JonSnow;

...

int AryaStark;

...

// int DaenerysTargaryen;

foo();
   ^ current currsor
```

I want to change foo() to:

```
foo(JonSnow, AryaStark, TyrionLannister, DaenerysTargaryen)
```

I have used two methods to do the job so far:

1. use autocomplete plugin such as ycm, i can type "js", and select "JonSnow" from popup list.
2. sometimes plugin can't help me, because target variable is commented or it's some compound expression or whatever reason, i have to copy and paste by myself.

   I have to move my cursor to the variable if i want to copy it, sometimes i use <kbd>G</kbd>, sometimes i use <kbd>H</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and a lot of <kbd>{</kbd>,<kbd>}</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd>, some times even<kbd>/</kbd> seemes to be a good choice.

   Sometimes i copy all variables into different registers <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>..., then <kbd>`</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to go back to foo(), paste from <kbd>a</kbd>, add comma,  paste from <kbd>b</kbd>, add comma, etc. Sometimes i copy only one variable, go back to foo(), add comma, paste it, then repeat the process for other variables.

Method 2 is quite awkward, i hate it so much that sometimes i type the arguments manually(i know i shouldn't do it manually).

How should i change my workflow? What's your workflow for this problem?

Comment: Macros? Since it's either autocomplete or visit each variable for the latter create a macro that yank-appends each variable name (plus comma) to a single register. Visit each and run the macro (just `@@` after the first stop). Then paste the now populated register to the funcdef. Done.  Not fancy but relatively painless.

Comment: Thank you @BLayer , Macro is another viable option.

Comment: Autocomplete works fine if you use vim’s regular `<C-n>` and `<C-p>`. Ive never needed a better completion system than `help ins-comp`.

Comment: I had to admit, i'm spoiled by ycm. There are 13 mappings in :h ins-comp , i was frightened away when i saw it 2 or 3 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @D. Ben Knoble mentioned, I'd use `<C-n>` and `<C-p>` which will look mostly (but not only, cf `:help i_ctrl-n` for more information) in the words in the opened files, making the completion quite "local", and appropriate in your case.

Regarding the completion of Vim, I'd encourage you to have a look at it, my favourite ones being the path completion (`:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F`) and the whole line completion (`i_CTRL-X_CTRL-L`). But the tag completion is definitely worth having a look. Take them and get comfortable with them one after the other, and it will be less daunting.

Comment: Thanks, i_CTRL-X_CTRL-L is nice. <c-n> and <c-p> only works for keywords, it won't work for compound expression such as `std::max(i, j)`, it also won't work for words in commented lines(maybe can be changed via some configuration). I'm considering some yank ring plugin right now. And i can't leave ycm...i'm beyond saving.

Comment: Are you sure about ` it also won't work for words in commented lines`? I tried with `vim -u NONE /tmp/test.c`, added a line `// int hello = 1;` and in the next line typed `h<c-n>` which completed with `hello`.

Comment: As i said "maybe can be changed via some configuration".  I guess some c or cpp filetype or syntax plugin stopped it from being recongnized as keywords..

Comment: By the way. Ycm also support keywords auto completion, it's marked as identifier, but i think it's the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, the fact that it was a c file was just an example, it behaves the same with any type of file, even plain text. `<c-n>` and `<c-p>` will complete any word, in comment or not, which are in the opened buffers. However if you want to complete a compound expression as the one you mentioned you'll need some external pluging indeed I am afraid.

Comment: No need to sorry. I don't think it can be complete via plugin, you have to do it manually in some level. One thing i'm pretty sure is that i don't want to do `"ay`,`"by`,`"cy` kind operation, it's too awkward.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. For the simple variables, I hope `c-n` and `c-p` will help you and that the different completions in Vim will also help you in general.